# Get matching substring from a string

Tags: c#, string, substring

I want to get the matching substring from a given string. Below is the example what I am trying to get:

```
string name = Science;

string sentence = Topper in Science;
```

I want to compare name inside the substring of sentence and get to know whether it is present or not.

Comment: [`string.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) would the job. `if(sentence .Contains(name))`

Comment: Just for the sake of whatever, but keep in mind that, by default, the compare is Case Sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

```
sentance.Contains(name)
```

Will do it for you.